# Best solution for a Sonar issue related to "throws"

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am using SonarQube to improve coding quality but I got a bug here that I don't know the best solution.

I call a Spring's method with the following signature:

```
T read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, 
NonTransientResourceException;
```

As I just have to call this method and I have no intention to treat any error, I  defined my method like this:

```
ItemTransacaoEnvioVO read() throws 
UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException,  
Exception
```

But I get this Sonar bug:

```
Remove the declaration of thrown exception 
'org.springframework.batch.item.ParseException' which is a subclass of 
'java.lang.Exception'
...
etc
```

Then I changed like Sonar wants:

```
ItemTransacaoEnvioVO read() throws Exception
```

And I get this:

```
Define and throw a dedicated exception instead of using a generic one.
```

Thinking in the best practices and coding quality what would be the best solution for this problem?

Java 8, Sonar

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the version of SonarJava (found in the Update Center: **Administration > System > Update Center**)

Answer (score 2):

If you plan to handle `Exception`, `UnexpectedInputException`, `ParseException`, `NonTransientResourceException`,
or if you want to let users of your custom class handle these exceptions,
then the issue is acceptable and you can mark it False Positive or Won't Fix in your SonarQube.

But it's unlikely that you, or users of your custom class will be interested in handling all those low-level exceptions separately.
If that's the case,
then it will make sense to define your custom exception,
and throw that instead.
Catch all of Spring's exceptions and preserve them in the custom exception in case somebody might want to see the original cause.

Comment: The only point here is that Spring throws too many exceptions. Not me.

Answer (score 0):

Don't throw generic exceptions. You should be subclassing Exception and then throwing your subclass, so that the type of the exception actually provides information about what is going on, allowing clients of the function to catch and treat it appropriately.

Comment: The only point is that Spring is throwing those exceptions. So the generic one comes from Spring.